# typescript parseInt not working as expected, receiving NaN

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am tryng to parse a simple string to number but i am receiving NaN,

The string is `"A20181"` ... i have been reading several post in diferents web but i dont find the solution...

To parse a string to number in typescript, is like javascript right? i remember i did something similar and it was working, what i am doing wrong?

```
var text = 'A20181'
var integer = parseInt(text, 10)

console.log(integer) // receiving NaN....
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you need [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), not `parseInt()` later you can use `parseInt()` to make it integer. Because `parseInt()` returns -

> An integer number parsed from the given string. If the **first** character
>   cannot be converted to a number, **NaN** is returned.

```js
var text = 'A20181A'
var integer = parseInt(text.replace(/\D/g, ""),10); //replace that is non-digit character

console.log(integer)
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Return_value)

Comment: oh.... damn, what a mistake, that's right, i needed a regex... THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

This question is not related to Typescript, you are trying to parse a string that is not a number. [ParseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) meant to parse a string that is a number such as "10"

You can remove the **`A`** and then parse that string.

```js
var text = 'A20181'
var integer = parseInt(text.replace(/[^\d]*/, ''), 10)

console.log(integer)
```